# Easy way to find find itinerant max value in grouped pandas list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where I have multiple value entries per year and some properties per entry. I want to find the maximum value per year and return that as a new data frame (to keep the other properties in the data frame), but only if the value in a year is greater than what it was in the years before (something like the "All-time record value per year"). So far I can find the max value per year, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[2015, 40, 'Property A'],
                        [2012, 35, 'Property B'],
                        [2014, 37, 'Property C'], 
                        [2013, 43, 'Property D'], 
                        [2013, 40, 'Property E'], 
                        [2015, 41, 'Property F']], 
                  columns=['Year', 'Value', 'Property'])
df_sorted_max = df.loc[df.groupby('Year')['Value'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_sorted_max)
```

where the output then is

```
   Year  Value    Property
0  2012     35  Property B
1  2013     43  Property D
2  2014     37  Property C
3  2015     41  Property F
```

This is almost what I want, expect for 2014 where I would like the value of 2013 with its according properties to go (since the value was greater in 2013 than it was in 2014). So the desired outcome would be

```
   Year  Value    Property
0  2012     35  Property B
1  2013     43  Property D
2  2014     43  Property D
3  2015     43  Property D
```

Is there a good way to achieve this with pandas?

Comment: After running your code, you can do `df_sorted_max.mask(df_sorted_max['Value'].diff() < 0).ffill()`

Comment: If I read this correctly, this works in this example where the the discrepancy is only in one year since it compares pairs - in my bigger data set this is not necessarily the case though. Should've chosen a better example, sorry!

Comment: It'd be great if you could amend your _current_ example to show a counter case to the solution provided, that always helps move the discussion forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_sorted_max['cummax_value'] = df_sorted_max.Value.cummax()

print(
    df_sorted_max.merge(
        df_sorted_max.groupby('cummax_value')[['Property']].first(),
        on="cummax_value"
    )
)
```

Results in

```
   Year  Value  Property_x  cummax_value  Property_y
0  2012     35  Property B            35  Property B
1  2013     43  Property D            43  Property D
2  2014     37  Property C            43  Property D
3  2015     60  Property A            60  Property A
```

After which you can just drop the original columns.

The secret sauce here is the `cummax` function.

Comment: Have to quickly check whether that works in my bigger dataset (new to both pandas and stack overflow), but `cummax()` seems pretty much like what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

A new record columns that represent the past record

```
df['record'] = df.Value.cummax().shift(1).fillna(-1e9)
```

Then you create a boolean Series determining if you want to keep a value:

```
keep = df.record<df.Value
```

Finally you delete values you want to remove and forward fill:

```
from numpy import nan
df.loc[~keep, 'Value'] = nan
df.loc[~keep, 'Property'] = nan

df=df.ffill()
```

You can change the rule for keep if you want to take into account new data where the Value is the same as the previous maximum.